# Cant get AMQP to load for apache2 on 64bit linux, php5.4

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, 64-bit, amqp

I have successfully PECL installed AMQP after installing rabbitmq-c as per the instructions at http://www.php.net/manual/en/amqp.installation.php

The .so file is created and I have added it to php.ini, but when I restart apache I get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/amqp.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/amqp.so: undefined symbol: amqp_open_socket in Unknown on line 0
```

This happens on both Ubuntu 12.10 64bit PHP 5.4.6 and Ubuntu 13.04 64bit PHP 5.4.9

It does however work start up as expected on Ubuntu 12.04 32bit PHP 5.3.10

Has anyone managed to get AQMP to install on 64bit PHP 5.4? Does anyone know whether it is the PHP version or the fact that it's a 64bit OS that might be causing the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you don't have librabbitmq installed or librabbitmq version is incompatible with php-amqp extension or library placed in wrong location.

Comment: Thanks, any idea what versions are needed/where the libraries should be? I have tried the Ubuntu versions of librabbitmq0 and librabbitmq-dev but then PECL can't compile the amqp extension. PECL does compile with the latest librabbitmq from https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c but then I get the error mentioned above on apache2 startup.

Comment: I guess you used librabbitmq from master branch, which may be not a good idea. Dunno, maybe you should try tag 'rabbitmq-c-v0.3.0', it works for me. Btw, try to follow the installation manual from official installation howto from https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c. To feigure out library availability look this question http://serverfault.com/questions/54736/how-to-check-if-a-library-is-installed

Comment: That worked! Thanks very much. The problem was indeed with the master branch. Tag rabbitmq-c-v0.3.0 works as expected.